# find exec output stream

Tags: linux, bash, find, rename

Hi Stackoverflow guys...

Problem:

```
ls W
W/W-5974.jpg
W/W-5642.jpg
W/W-5789.jpg
W/W-5199.jpg
W/W-7565.jpg
W/W-2270.jpg
.....
```

As you can see i have many files in the folder W and the same ammount of file in all other folders.

I have prepared a command to put the information in a text file for caffe

```
find . -name '*.jpg'  -exec env f={} bash -c 'echo $f "replaceme" | cut -c 3- ' ';'
```

this generates a list like this:

```
W/W-8872.jpg replaceme
W/W-9262.jpg replaceme
W/W-6049.jpg replaceme
W/W-3995.jpg replaceme
W/W-6476.jpg replaceme
W/W-7633.jpg replaceme
W/W-5974.jpg replaceme
W/W-5642.jpg replaceme
W/W-5789.jpg replaceme
```

But i want to have the Data like this:

```
W/W-8872.jpg W
W/W-9262.jpg W
A/A-6049.jpg A
D/D-3995.jpg D
D/D-6476.jpg D
x/x-7633.jpg x
W/W-5974.jpg W
l/l-5642.jpg l
W/W-5789.jpg W
```

replaceme should be replaced with the first character of the find output and the cut....

Question:
Can i do this with just this one liner? if not does some one have a recommendation? problem is that it needs to be very fast, because there are 800'000 files :-( Many greetings from BigData

Comment: `${f:0:1}` will expand to the first character of the `f` variable.

Comment: will test it immediately

Comment: @EtanReisner , final answer is with your help: --- find . -name '*.jpg'  -exec env f={} bash -c 'echo $f ${f:4:1} | cut -c 3- ' ';' ---- if you write it as a answer i can reward you ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Substring Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to get part of a string in the shell.

```
$ f=foobar
$ echo "${f:0:1}"
f
$ echo "${f:3:2}"
ba
```